# How to get the whole element with Kantu Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, kantu

Method `storeAttribute` works perfectly when I need to get an attribute like `href`:

```
xpath=(//span[@class='active'])@href
```

But how should I use it to get the whole element (`span` in this example)? I mean the whole html source text of the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with the storeText command.

So your target would be just:

```
xpath=(//span[@class='active'])
```

Set `Command` to `storeText` and set `Value` to the name of the desired `variable`.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. `storeText` is looking at DOM, not at the html source text. With this thing you can get only visible text. Try this command `xpath=(//div[@id='gallery-item'])` here `https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200000782/suits-sets.html`